# Standard protocol for multiplexing HTTP (for multiple requests)

Tags: http, http2

We have a web service that currently responds to around 3 million HTTP requests per second. Each back end server is capable of serving around 5 million requests. So the bottle-neck is the HTTP front ends.

So the problem is reversed to that of a load balancer situation. We have solved the problem by letting many front end servers aggregate incoming requests for around 1 millisecond. Once a full millisecond is reached for a particular front end server, we send all the batched up requests (around 100) to the back end server using an existing single socket connection.

This means that our back end servers gets requests containing a hundred original HTTP requests and answers with a response containing a hundred requests.

Is there a standard protocol to multiplex/batch/aggregate HTTP requests? The multiplexing in HTTP2 seams to be focused on multiple responses to a single request.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP2 multiplexing is NOT for multiple responses to a single request.
HTTP2 has been designed to allow multiple requests over a single connection without head of line blocking - ie responses can return in arbitrary order.

Depending on the size of your responses, I think that HTTP2 may well offer you something.....   however if your responses are large and/or they all take about the same time so that head of line blocking is not an issue, then pipelined HTTP1 is probably going to eat less CPU.

Answer (score 0):

No, the multiplexing of HTTP/2 is full request-response pairs over a single physical connection. In the HTTP/2 case, a browser should be able to view a site with hundreds of objects using a single TCP connection.

This thus sounds like a protocol that could suit your use case.